# SAX - Read HTML content without CDATA

Tags: java, html, xml, xml-parsing, sax

I´m using SAX parser in Java and it's mandatory. I need to parse an XML with HTML tags that I must read like content, and I can´t use CDATA because I can´t change the XML file. The XML file is something like that:

```
<start id="123">
    <tag1>text1</tag1>
    <tag2>
        This is an example
        <span>
            text inside an HTML tag
        </span>
        <p>
            ABCDEFG<b>HIJK</b>LMNOP
        </p>
    </tag2>
</start>
```

What I need is that when I get the content of tag2, the content must be:

```
This is an example
<span>text inside an HTML tag</span>
<p>ABCDEFG<b>HIJK</b>LMNOP</p>
```

This is a test that I did and the content doesn´t show the HTML tags:

```
boolean istag2 = false;

StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    System.out.println("Start Element :" + qName);
    if (qName.equals("tag2")) {
        istag2 = true;
    }
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equals("tag2")) {
        istag2 = false;
        String fullText = text.toString();
        System.out.println("tag2 full_text: " + fullText);
    }
}

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    if (istag2) {
        text.append(new String(ch, start, length));
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your actual problem? Do you have some code you've tried?

Comment: @NicGibson I just edit the question adding the code

Comment: So what output are you getting? Are you suggesting the startElement trace includes the start, tag1, and tag2 elements, but doesn't include the span or p elements? That would be pretty weird.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I might understand where your expectations are wrong. I think you might be expecting that the strings `"<span>"` and `"<p>"` are passed to your application by calls on the `characters()` method. But that's not what happens: they are passed by calls on `startElement()` and `endElement()`. If you want to build up a string containing these tags in lexical form, you will need to do something like:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    System.out.println("Start Element :" + qName);
    if (qName.equals("tag2")) {
        inTag2 = true;
    } else if (inTag2) {
        text.append("<" + qName);
        // TODO: serialize any attributes
        text.append(">")
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it takes the content of tag2 properly (the strings "<span>" and "<p>" are passed to my application), but don´t get the content of other tag, for example the content of tag1

Comment: Since your `characters()` method explicitly discards anything that's not within tag2, why should that be surprising?